# data.table substring on column

Tags: r, data.table, substring

Given this data.table

```
DT = data.table(item=c("item1 - description one", "item2 - description two", "item3 - description three"), sales=1:3)

DT
                        item sales
1:   item1 - description one     1
2:   item2 - description two     2
3: item3 - description three     3
```

How can I easily get output that looks like

```
      code sales
1:   item1     1
2:   item2     2
3:   item3     3
```

Probably very easy but thanks in advance.

Comment: Split on space, then keep the 1st value. Something like: `dt1$item_clean <- sapply(strsplit(dt1$item, " "), function(i)i[1])`

Comment: Simply `DT[, item := sub('\\s+.*', '', item)]`

Comment: `data.table(code = substr(DT[[1]], 1, regexpr(' ', DT[[1]])-1), sales = DT[[2]])`

Comment: Thanks to all of you for prompt responses... sorry for duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
DT[, item:=gsub(item, pattern=" - [a-zA-Z ]+", replacement="")]
setnames(DT, "item", "code")

#    code sales
#1: item1     1
#2: item2     2
#3: item3     3
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael for your prompt response. Worked like a charm.